# Как перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, помогите:

```
if (какая то переменная){
какой то код
}else{
тут нужно сделать перенаправление на другую страницу
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(true) {
// some code
} else {
header("Location: http://someurl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://site.com', true, 301);
```